# ActionLink not being hidden

Tags: javascript, html, actionlink

I have an actionLink that I would to hide whenever I want. Therefore, I set the display to none. However, for some reason, this is not working..

This is the actionlink:

```
@Html.ActionLink("abc", "TwitterAuth", new { id = "twitterBtn" });
```

I tried this but did not work:

```
@Html.ActionLink("abc", "TwitterAuth", new { id = "twitterBtn", style="display:none" });
```

With Javascript, which gives the erro Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null:

```
document.getElementById('twitterBtn').style.display = 'none';
```

What am I doing wrong please? Because I'm at a loss..

Thanks.

Comment: I've seen other examples of logic like this that used `@id`.  Do you need an `@` in front of those attribute keys?

Comment: Actually I didnt work, I did the @ with the style not the id, which worked with the style, however the id is still not found on Javascript

Comment: If you do the lookup in your console does it work?  If you put the @ on the id and then try the lookup in the console does it work?

Comment: with the @, it still gives the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Comment: In your code, right, but what about in the console. If you run that lookup yourself

Comment: Ok, so I "fixed" half of the error.. I made it like this
@Html.ActionLink("Continue with Twitter", "TwitterAuth", null, new { id = "twitterBtn" } ).. However, now, the style=display:none is not working.. even with inline css, it does not make it not displayed..

Comment: Finally fixed it.. In my javascript, I did a small mistake of putting an if statement outside another if statement instead of inside of it, which was conflicting with it. Thanks though!